# Jquery widget triggered event not being handled or fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget

I have a very simple widget outlined that appears to fire an event via  `_trigger` that I cant seem to bind to:

```
; (function ($) {
    $.widget('testspace.ftpWidget', {
        options: {},
        widgetEventPrefix: 'ftpwidget:',
        _create: function () {
            var that = this;
            that.paused = ko.observable(false);
        },
        _triggerPlayerInitialized: function () {
            console.log("player initialized");
            this._trigger("testeventname", null, null);
            console.log("player testeventname supposedly fired");
        },
        pause: function () {
            this.paused(!this.paused());
            console.log("player paused");
            this._triggerPlayerInitialized();
        },
        _destroy: function () { },
        _setOption: function (key, value) { }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

In an html file:

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      $('#videoA').ftpWidget();
      var widget = $('#videoA').data("testspace-ftpWidget");
      console.log(widget);
      $(widget).on("ftpwidget:testeventname", function (event, data) {
          console.log("widget initialized");
      });
      widget.pause();
 });
```

And console output:

[image: Console output]

Why is this event not being handled / or is it not even being fired? How can I debug this?

**Update:**

[This answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYNe0.gif), though not my problem, gave me a hint. The OP is calling the `on` binding from an element `body`. So I changed

```
 $(widget).on("ftpwidget:testeventname", function (event, data) {
```

to

```
 $("body").on("ftpwidget:testeventname", function (event, data) {
```

and it worked, so does

```
 $("#video").on("ftpwidget:testeventname", function (event, data) {
```

So now I have it working but don't really understand why. Is it a scope "thing"?
I was thinking

"I want to register for the `testeventname` on `widget`"

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

_trigger itself can actually call your function. In the first parameter you're specifying the name of the callback function you want to trigger. So if you were to change:

```
$('#videoA').ftpWidget();
```

to

```
$('#videoA').ftpWidget({
  testeventname: function (event, data) {
    console.log("widget initialized");
  }
});
```

that would also work.

[Jquery-UI: How to Use the Widget Factory](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/#adding-callbacks)